# send mail with smtp and Qt

Tags: qt, smtp

I have a problem in sending mails by Qt

my code is based on this http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/2221-Sending-email-using-Qt.

but the problem is that the program told me that the user was not authenticated

[image: screen shot]

thanks for the help

Comment: Sounds like your SMTP server telling you are not authenticated, are you passing any credentials?

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote a modified version of that very same code that handles SMTP auth and multiple recipients, you can grab it [from GitHub](https://github.com/nicholassmith/Qt-SMTP). It's not perfect but it should work, you'll need a username and password for your mail server encoded as Base64.

Answer (score 0):

Witold Wysota's qwwsmtpclient class might be what you're looking for— it's a reasonably complete implementation of the mail-submission part of SMTP but it's just a simple class not a part of a huge framework.